# Admob - Application showing Adds but Requests not updated

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I integrated Admob adds in my android application for the first time. When I am running it on my device, it shows adds but on admob still the request count is 0. My App is still not on Google Play because before uploading it, I wanted to make sure that the adds are working properly. 
I added my publisher id as the AD_UNIT_ID in the android application.
Please shed some light on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly see the ad and you're completely sure the `UNIT_ID` is correct, I wouldn't worry too much about this, since your own displays/clicks don't count. Additionally, if you've set your device to be a testing one, this won't increase the count of your hits or requests.

Once you upload your app to Google Play you'll (hopefully) see it increase as far as users use your app.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the point you mentioned about setting the device as a testing one? And how not to do so?

Comment: @SayanSil I hope this helps: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices